# Get placeholder text color using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

[image]I have a test scenario to verify the color of placeholder text in a input element.
I'm not sure how to do it using selenium.
My html

```
    <div class="pe-input">
    <label for="input-text-active-PH">Active Basic text input with placeholder :</label>
    <input type="text" id="input-text-active-PH" placeholder="Basic text input field" value="">
</div>
```

This is the css

```
    .pe-input input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.pe-input textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #6d6d6d; }
```

Can someone help me how to fetch the placeholder text color using selenium with java ?

Comment: Can you show your own attempt ?

Comment: Do you mean you want label text color or input attribute placeholder text color??

Comment: I don't see an option in selenium libraries to fetch the css color of the placeholder. I'm only able to get the input color but not the placeholder's color within the input element.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value from css, u can use getCssValue() method like below code:

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#input-text-active-PH")).getCssValue("color");
```

This will return the css color value of that element.

Comment: your statement will return color of input element but not the placeholder text.